# How to dynamically update HistogramDataset with two series in jfreechart?

Tags: java, charts, histogram, jfreechart

I want to dynamically update two separate series in a jfree chart histogram. When i look at HistogramDataset it doesn't seem like there is a method for that. Is this possible? I know it can be done in SimpleHistogramDataset but I need to have two series on this chart.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some alternatives:

1. Replace the `HistogramDataset` with each update:

   ```
   chart.getXYPlot().setDataset(newDataset);
   ```
2. Add a second `SimpleHistogramDataset` and `XYItemRenderer` to the plot:

   ```
   SimpleHistogramDataset newDataset = createDataset();
   chart.getXYPlot().setDataset(1, newDataset);
   XYItemRenderer renderer = new XYBarRenderer();
   renderer.setBasePaint(Color.blue);
   chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(1, renderer);
   ```
3. Create a custom `AbstractIntervalXYDataset` that supports mutation.