# Create jfreechart histogram via bin values?

Tags: java, statistics, histogram, jfreechart

Does `jFreeChart` support creating a histogram from an array of bin values? I'd like to plot an array of bin values update the chart as new samples arrive. I would need to support multiple series on this chart and update it dynamically if possible. Can this be done with `SimpleHistogramDataset` and `SimpleHistogramBin`?

I know I can use the `SimpleHistogramDataset` which allows dynamic updates but I have not tried two datasets at once. I'd also like to know if the normal `HistogramDataset` allows dynamic updates, I kind of assumed it does not since you have to specify the values array argument up front.

Comment: I'd update an `Image` or `Raster` in the background and recreate the histogram, _pari passu_, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513).

Comment: You can add another `SimpleHistogramDataset` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44698067/230513).